# Maintain dependency between two tables while executing triggers in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper, order-of-execution

How we can maintain dependency between two tables while executing triggers in oracle??
As we know we can use follows clause if we have single table and multiple triggers based on that table but my concern is that is there any way if we have 2 different tables and there are different triggers based on these table so how can we maintain some proper sequence in this case.

For example:
--Table1:

```
CREATE TABLE emp(
empId number PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName varchar2(20),
LastName varchar2(20),
Email varchar2(25),
PhoneNo varchar2(25),
Salary number(8)
);
```

--Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_1(
empId number PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName varchar2(20),
LastName varchar2(20),
Email varchar2(25),
PhoneNo varchar2(25),
Salary number(8)
);
```

Trigger on `EMP`:

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER TRIGGER_emp 
BEFORE INSERT OR AFTER UPDATE ON emp
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  
    dbms_output.put_line ('MY EXECUTE ORDER FOR EMP IS SECOND -EXECUTED');  
END; 
/
```

Trigger on `EMP1`:

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER TRIGGER_emp1
BEFOR INSERT OR AFTER UPDATE ON emp_1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  
    dbms_output.put_line ('MY EXECUTE ORDER FOR EMP IS FIRST -EXECUTED');  
END; 
/
```

Now i want this trigger TRIGGER_emp1 will execute first and then this trigger will execute TRIGGER_emp last. Is it possible to do so in oracle

Please guide me in this.

Comment: What action do you think will cause both triggers to fire - in any order? You can't insert into both table simultaneously. What you're asking still doesn't seem to make sense. What do you mean by "maintain dependency between two tables" - in your example they have the same structure (which is strange) but don't otherwise seem to be related.

Comment: (Also - previous questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73950947/266304) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73957407/266304) - both now deleted.)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a clone of user who recently posted two questions regarding the same subject. It was said that you can't do that. Triggers "belong" to a single table, which means that

- you insert (or update) values in `emp` table, which then
- fires trigger `trigger_emp` which *does something*

  - in your case, it just displays a message (you might, or might not see; that depends on a tool you use)
- as nothing happened to table `emp1`, trigger `trigger_emp1` won't fire - why would it?

  - if you want it to fire, then let the first trigger (`trigger_emp`) affect rows in `emp1` table (insert a row or update existing values)

    - once you do that, `trigger_emp1` will do whatever it does

---

Maybe, just *maybe* you should consider creating a **stored procedure** which contains code that works with rows in both `emp` and `emp1` table. Then, instead of relying on triggers and worry whether they will fire, when will they fire and in which sequence, your main transaction would actually call the **procedure** which would then do the job (and affect rows in `emp` and `emp1`, in any order you want - that's easy to do as you'd just rearrange statements within the procedure).